# Getting NoSuchMethodError while using Aws SQS extended library when reading from s3 bucket name

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Getting below Error message when using aws extended sqs client lib.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
            at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSExtendedClient.getTextFromS3(AmazonSQSExtendedClient.java:1192)
            at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSExtendedClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSExtendedClient.java:351)
            at com.zebra.SQSCofigCredentials.getMessagesFromQueue(SQSCofigCredentials.java:143)
            at com.zebra.WorkerSQSLoader.run(WorkerSQSLoader.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Below is the Pom.XML

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.122</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.138</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The program consumes the messages from SQS and post the message to Kafka topic.

Comment: Why are you using two different versions of the AWS libraries?  The extended SQS client uses 1.11.122 - don't jump ahead with the SQS library.

Comment: I am getting this error only when I run on clusters as yarn application. I am able to run successfully on Edge node.